# "export VAR=thing && someCommand" reports "export: `&&': not a valid identifier"

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable and execute a command in a single line, like this:

```
export PUB_CACHE=/app/src/.pub-cache && dart-sdk/bin/dart server.dart
```

(Don't ask why... it's complicated ;))

It's being invoked by someone elses script; and it fails like this:

```
export: `&&': not a valid identifier6:44 PM
export: `dart-sdk/bin/dart': not a valid identifier6:44 PM
export: `server.dart': not a valid identifier
```

It seems like the entire rest of the line is being passed to export. It's entirely possible it's due to the way they're running the command and I can't fix it, but it's also possibly just my Linux noobishness.

Is there something wrong with my command? Can I easily make it execute both things individually?

Comment: I'm confused; won't that add it to what's being exported?  I need the var defined and then Dart calling

Comment: is it really using bash, as you've tagged? It's acting almost like a Bourne (not Again) shell with the export syntax. Try breaking it into multiple lines (PUB_CACHE=...; export PUB_CACHE; dart-sdk/bin/dart...)

Comment: The command works for me here (except that I don't have any dart installation, so the second part fails). Are you sure you're not using `dash` or any other shell? What does `echo $0` print? What if you remove the `&&` or replace it by `;`?

Comment: Not answering the question, but you want `env`, not `export` -- `env VAR=thing someCommand`, or with bash, just `VAR=thing someCommand`

Comment: btw, works with bash v2.03.

Comment: OMG… bash should add some code for warning their users that they are using software old as the hills or is this Debian stable? (SCNR)  Seriously, where in God's name did you find a bash version _this_ _old_‽

Comment: If bash adds a warning, that warning by definition will not be there in versions of bash "as old as the hills", but only in newer versions, making the warning moot.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Then add a notice saying: "This software is **not** as old as the hills" :-)

Comment: @AndreasWiese Where most (read all) bash are found: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/

Comment: TODO: Submit a patch for the output of `bash --version` adding `Certified to be newer than at least some hills!`.

Comment: Thanks for all the info; I assumed it was bash but have limited access to the machine. I was able to fix it using ENV (see answer).

Comment: you can add ; between the commands

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it with this:

```
env PUB_CACHE=/app/src/.pub-cache dart-sdk/bin/dart server.dart
```

or just

```
PUB_CACHE=/app/src/.pub-cache dart-sdk/bin/dart server.dart
```

Didn't realise you could pass commands on the end.